# How to build barchart with dual axis in ggplot R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, tidyverse, data-visualization

I want to plot barchart with dual axis, where 'cost' variable is reflected on the **right y-axis**. After I specified sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*2, name ="Cost") however as it seems, the curve is not adjusted according to axis on right

```
df <- data.frame (model  = c("A", "B", "C","D","E","F"),
                  share = c(12,20,15,9,60,20),
                  sale = c(16,25,18,14,67,28),
                  cost = c(14,19,28,24,57,28))

#set levels of model by cost
df$model <- factor(df$model, levels = arrange(df, desc(df$cost))$model)

library(tidyverse)

df_long <- df %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = -model
  ) 


plt <- ggplot(df_long, aes(x = model, y= value, label=value))+
  geom_col(data = filter(df_long, name != "cost"), aes(fill=name), position = position_dodge())+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("blue", "grey"))+
  geom_line(data = filter(df_long, name == "cost"), aes(color = name, group = 1), size = 1)+
  scale_color_manual(values = "red")+
  geom_text(data = filter(df_long, name == "cost"), size = 3,hjust=0, vjust=-0.5)+
  #geom_label(data = filter(df_long, name == "cost"), hjust=0, vjust=-0.5)+
  scale_y_continuous(
    name = "Sale and Share",
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*2, name ="Cost")
  )+
  theme_minimal()+
  theme(legend.title=element_blank())


plt
```

[image]

Comment: `sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*2, name ="Cost")` Here you are saying that the second Y-axis is 2 times the primary Y-axis. The second axis must be a linear-transformation of the primary axis. However, why do you need a second axis? The range of 'cost' is the same as the other ones

Comment: In my original data, scales are not the same so I want to set it automatically somehow and plot curve according to it

Comment: How are the scales different? Cost is 2 times bigger? Try that the `df` example in your post represents that differences.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**
We have to adapt `y=value/2` in `geom_line()`:
However this will cause another issue with `geom_text()`

```
plt <- ggplot(df_long, aes(x = model, y=value, label=value))+
  geom_col(data = filter(df_long, name != "cost"), aes(fill=name), position = position_dodge())+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("blue", "grey"))+
  geom_line(data = filter(df_long, name == "cost"), aes(color = name,  y= value/2, group = 1), size = 1)+
  scale_color_manual(values = "red")+
  geom_text(data = filter(df_long, name == "cost"), size = 3,hjust=0, vjust=5)+
  #geom_label(data = filter(df_long, name == "cost"), hjust=0, vjust=-0.5)+
  scale_y_continuous(
    name = "Sale and Share",
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*2, name ="Cost")
  )+
  theme_minimal()+
  theme(legend.title=element_blank())


plt
```

[image]

you have to devide y by the same you multiple in sec.axis. In your case: y= value/2

If you want to automate:

```
coeff <- 2

plt <- ggplot(df_long, aes(x = model, y= value/coeff, label=value))+
  geom_col(data = filter(df_long, name != "cost"), aes(fill=name), position = position_dodge())+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("blue", "grey"))+
  geom_line(data = filter(df_long, name == "cost"), aes(color = name, group = 1), size = 1)+
  scale_color_manual(values = "red")+
  geom_text(data = filter(df_long, name == "cost"), size = 3,hjust=0, vjust=-0.5)+
  #geom_label(data = filter(df_long, name == "cost"), hjust=0, vjust=-0.5)+
  scale_y_continuous(
    name = "Sale and Share",
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*coeff, name ="Cost")
  )+
  theme_minimal()+
  theme(legend.title=element_blank())


plt
```

[image]

Comment: Now everything are just reflected on right y-axis

Comment: bars must be reflected to left axis, while red line on rigt

Comment: This is a good approach if the differences in scales are linearly related @Georgecarrick

Comment: However in this case Y-axis is wrongly showing the right values of the bars

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72642914/r-how-to-customize-the-legend-in-plot-ly